Can’t refresh reflections using API v3
I am trying to make a request to trigger reflection refreshes for a dataset with:
String url = "https://dremio-ee.k8s.<env>.<org>.net/api/v3/dataset/<id>/reflection";
    String AUTHORIZATION = "Authorization";
    String BEARER_S = "Bearer %s";
    SimpleJsonHttpRequest request = new SimpleJsonHttpRequest.Builder(
            SimpleJsonHttpRequest.Method.POST,
            url)
            .addHeader(AUTHORIZATION, String.format(BEARER_S, token.getToken()))
            .build();
    ...
    <building the request, setting headers, etc.>
    ...
    HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

But I’m getting: Bad HTTP status returned {“errorMessage”:“HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed”,“moreInfo”:“”}
Does anyone know why it would be giving this error?

Can you add what version of Dremio you're using here?

Try "_dremio%s" instead of "Bearer %s"
Build
25.1.1-202409260159070462-716c0676
Edition
Community Edition

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
